# HSQLDB - Internal logging to database tables

Tags: logging, hsqldb, rdbms

Is it possible to have internal event and statement logging inside database tables?

This would be useful, instead of having `.app.log` and  `.sql.log` files, so that the logs could be transparently encrypted and queried as tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with AFTER INSERT, AFTER UPDATE and AFTER DELETE triggers defined on the tables you want to log. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/triggers-chapt.html#trc_after_triggers

Comment: This however would work only for statement logging but not for event logging, right?